# How to define an array element using a PHP variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, element

community.

I've been looking for an answer, but not close enough to this scenario

I have a code like this (actually working fine):

```
array('desc'=>'Home')
```

It is working defining it as text (Home) but I would rather to use it as a PHP variable due multilanguage site. Using the language package I have a variable such:

```
$lang['HOME'] = 'Home';
```

So depending on the language selected, the value changes

In other words, I need the array to have the variable value as the element

```
array('desc'=>'variablehere')
```

Can anyone plese let me know what am I missing? I have tried to set it as variable, as echo and so other ways.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's wrong with -- `array('desc' => $variablehere )` ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$myArray = array('desc' => $variable);
```

or

```
$myArray = array(
    'desc' => $desc,
    'name' => $name
);
```

In your case:

```
$lang = array('HOME' => $homeVariable);
```

Comment: +1 and deleted mine :) Didn't realise you got there just before me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi-dimensional array. e.g., given something like

```
$lang = 'en';
$key = 'desc';
```

The exact array structure depends on your needs, but it could either be primarily by language, or by key-to-translate:

language-based:

```
$translations = array(
   'en' => array('desc' => 'foo'),
   'fr' => array('desc' => 'bar')
);

$text_to_display = $translations['en']['desc']; // produces 'foo'
```

or

```
$translations = array(
    'desc' => array(
        'en' => array('desc' => 'foo'),
        'fr' => array('desc' => 'bar')
    )
)

$text_to_display = $translations['desc']['fr']; // produces 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a translate function instead:

```
// It can be key-based, i.e., t('home_string'), or literal like below
t('Home');


function t($text, $language = NULL)
{
    if (!$language) {
        // determine visitor's language
    }

    // look up translation in db/file
    // if none found just return $text as is

}
```